# Como não permitir o zoom do celular no App?

Tags: angularjs, ionic3, ionic2, angular-6

Bom dia galera,
Estou precisando não deixar o zoom do celular do usuário afetar o meu App.
Utilizei o componentes do viewreport:

```
content="width=device-width, height=device-height, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"
```

Porém, não funcionou :(. Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1):

Se for apenas para mobile, experimente:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>`